# SQL unpivot of multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I would like the following wide table to be unpivotted but only where a user has a true value against the field, along with the appropriate date.
[image]
Current State:

---

| CUSTOMER_ID | First_Party_Email | Third_Party_Email | First_Party_Email_Date | Third_Party_Email_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40011111 | 1 | 1 | 2021-01-22 04:38:00.000 | 2021-01-17 06:38:00.000 |
| 50022222 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 2021-01-18 04:38:00.000 |
| 80066666 | 1 | NULL | 2021-01-24 05:38:00.000 | NULL |
| _______________ | _______________________ | _______________________ | _______________________________ | _______________________________ |

Required State:

---

| Customer_ID | Type | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40011111 | First_Party_Email | 1 | 22/01/2021 04:38 |
| 40011111 | Third_Party_Email | 1 | 17/01/2021 06:38 |
| 50022222 | Third_Party_Email | 1 | 18/01/2021 04:38 |
| 80066666 | First_Party_Email | 1 | 24/01/2021 05:38 |
| _______________________________________________________________________ |  |  |  |

Associated query to create table and my attempt that doesn't work:

```
create table Permissions_Obtained
(Customer_ID bigint
,First_Party_Email  bit
,Third_Party_Email  bit
,First_Party_Email_Date datetime    
,Third_Party_Email_Date datetime
)

insert into Permissions_Obtained
(Customer_ID
,First_Party_Email
,Third_Party_Email
,First_Party_Email_Date
,Third_Party_Email_Date
)
VALUES
(40011111,  1,      1,      '2021-01-22 04:38', '2021-01-17 06:38'),
(50022222,  NULL,   1,      NULL,               '2021-01-18 04:38'),
(80066666,  1,      NULL,   '2021-01-24 05:38', null)

select * 
from Permissions_Obtained

select 
customer_id, Permission
from Permissions_Obtained
unpivot
(
  GivenPermission
  for Permission in (
First_Party_Email, Third_Party_Email
)
) unpiv1, 
unpivot
(
  GivenPermissionDate
  for PermissionDate in (
First_Party_Email_Date, Third_Party_Email_Date
)
) unpiv2
where GivenPermission = 1

--drop table Permissions_Obtained
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple unpivots at the same time. Instead you can use Cross Apply or Inner join or union, union all or kind of joins depending on your requirement. I have added a sample answer for this using join and unpivot.

```
   SELECT 
       unpvt.Customer_ID 
       , [Type]
       ,  ISNULL(po.First_Party_Email ,po.Third_Party_Email) AS [Value] 
       ,CASE WHEN unpvt.Type = 'First_Party_Email' THEN po.First_Party_Email_Date
             ELSE  po.Third_Party_Email_Date  
             END AS  [Date]

     FROM   
        (
         SELECT 
           Customer_ID, First_Party_Email , Third_Party_Email  
           FROM Permissions_Obtained 
         ) p  
       UNPIVOT  
          (  [Value] FOR [Type]     IN   
               (First_Party_Email , Third_Party_Email )  
          )AS unpvt
          INNER JOIN  Permissions_Obtained [po] 
             on [po].Customer_ID = unpvt.Customer_ID
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Did you find your solution here ?@DarkWolve

Answer (score 1):

When un-pivoting multiple columns, `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` is often the easiest and most effective solution.

It creates a virtual table per-row of the previous table, and therefore un-pivots it into separate rows.

```sql
SELECT
    p.Customer_Id,
    v.[Type],
    v.Value,
    v.Date
FROM Permissions_Obtained p
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('First_Party_Email', p.First_Party_Email, p.First_Party_Email_Date),
    ('Third_Party_Email', p.Third_Party_Email, p.Third_Party_Email_Date)
) v([Type], Value, Date)
where v.Value IS NOT NULL;
```